# Using Runtime.exec not opening my xls file

Tags: java, file, xlsx, runtime.exec, rundll32

HAve this piece of code that opens the files:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]
                      {"rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler",
                       file.getAbsolutePath()});
```

where I have passed the file..
It's strange that its not opening some of the auto generated files in xlsx, where as it's able to open other xlsx files.
Unable to debug/find a solution, Pls help

Comment: Which auto generated files? What xslx?

Comment: Might be the path contains blanks?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("F:\\folder\\data\\file.xlsx"));
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: *"You can try the following:"*  Which is a lot more likely to actually work, especially on *nix and OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading xls using DLL methodology, you can use the new Apache API to open and access all the excel file data.

Please check the folllowing link for more details:
https://poi.apache.org/